# How to write this LaTeX formula

Tags: latex

I'm writing my internship report in latex but I have some problem with this 
formula 7 in this image below:

[image]

Can someone please give me the latex code for this formula?

Comment: There's nothing tricky at all about the expression you posted. It would be nice to see what you've already tried, and you'll have much better luck on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, when posting at tex.stackexchange.com, consider asking a *specific* question. Do you need to know how to enter equations *at all*, or is it about the specific "staggered" or "split" format of this equation?

Comment: No, I tried a code that genrate the equation but i didn't no how to convert letters into mathstyle , this is why i didn't have the same as the equation above thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\[
  \frac{%
    e^{v_m-1}
  }{%
    \frac{w_0 e^{w_o - n v_m} - n v_m}{w_o - n v_m} e^{v_m}
  - \frac{w_0 e^{w_o + n v_m} + n v_m}{w_o + n v_m}
  }
\]
```

The only interesting here is that if you want to make it look like it does in your paper, you'll have to change the math font.  E.g. `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.  And, possibly, add extra space where you want it.

Comment: thanks for your response, i tried your code ans this is what i get http://hpics.li/b2311f3 , it's a little different than the first equation also why the symbols 'e' in the equation haven't the same size , and thanks a lot for your response

Comment: I think you're copying it wrong.  For example, I have `e^{v_m}`, not `e^{w_m}` after the first fraction of the denominator, and I'm not using capital letters anywhere.